# Blender Tracking

Tags: rigging, tracking

[image]

hi guys, im new to blender, just wondering if its possible for me to switch the "follow path" for an object? i have 2 path and i wish for the person to walk along the path on the 2nd floor after it takes the lift up. Cant seem to figure out how to swtich it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can animate the influence setting of the constraints. make one be 1 and the other 0. switch them to switch paths.

Comment: hey i tried that but once i set the constraint to 0, the rigging flies to the world origin, (i wish to have it remain at that position)

Comment: Set key frames at the right frame. st frame 0 set second follow path to 0 and first to 1 key frame both. at frame you want second to take over swap them and key frame. rigging should jump from one path to the other but that’s hidden by the wall right?

Comment: sadly, no. i wanted to track the character taking the lift then walking on the 2nd floor

Comment: i am not a pro rigger, but it might be easier to just double your character and make it invisible on one path and visible on the other. Might be not the most performant way...but i think it would be the easiest to realize.

Comment: hey edgel3d, yea thats what i wanted! by any chance could you share the file with me for me to better understand how i can go about doing it?

Comment: Will post it up as an answer Lyon.  I buggered the link to the comment and have deleted it, so will do the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Animate a character to travel 2 consecutive paths with an elevator ride in between -  (Blend file below)

[image]

The character has 3 concurrently active parents.  As long as those parents don't move until they're supposed to, this works very well.

[image]

The character (char) has it's own 'Handle' (parent) so it's limbs can be animated similtaneously while the character as a whole is moved around the scene.  Even when rigged, it's wise to use a handle to parent and move the main armature, not animate it directly.  (i.e. if the rig and it's limb animations are working well, remove it's access in the Outliner so you can't inadvertently muck it up)

The char's Handle is parented to the lower path follower so it makes it's way to the lift platform.

To demonstrate another way of freeing up objects from constraints, the ground floor path-follower's action was baked to keyframes and that in turn was parented to the lift platform.  The lift isn't moving so there's no problem doing that.

Once on the platform the lift rises and takes the path follower with it.  That in turn takes the character's handle up, which in turn takes the character up.

The lift is parented to the upper floor's path follower and upon reaching that floor, and that path eventually activating, the lift is taken along the path and drags the entire entourage along with it.

Lift platforms aren't known for that sort of mobility so to conceal this, it's duplicated at the frame it reaches that floor and stops. This positions the copy precisely and with all animation cleared, sits there to provide us with a stationary and visible platform.  The copy is switched to invisible at frame 1 (in the Outliner) and visible at the switch-over frame.

The original is switched inversely, visible at frame 1 and invisible at the switch-over frame.

Our char is taken along that upper path until at the end, where it's to shimmy down the rope.  The char's handle is used to animate this and also take it back to the starting point.

[image]

Comment: An after-thought - From what I see it's probable there'll be more character action to follow in your project.  That's when you either bake the character's movements throughout, or leave this Blend file at it's final frame, and continue on in a new copy of the file.  All parentage and constraints would be removed from your character in the new file, meaning you can start it's timeline at frame 1 again continuing the action from where the original file left off.  Both would be rendered and appended seamlessly in the VSE.